# twig "render" method : how to get the request variables

Tags: php, twig, slim

The first parameter of twig "render" method must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, like $response here :

```
$app->get('/', function($request, $response, $args){
    $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig');
})->setName('home');
```

In my view 'home.twig', how can I use $response to get the request variables ?

Like this link http://link...?name=the_name

How can I get the GET 'name' variable in the home.view code ?

Using $response ?  It not, what's the purpose of $response there ?

Comment: Check the doc for `Request`object [here](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html#the-request-uri). The third parameters can be an array to be passed to the Twig engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this...

```
$request->getQueryParams()['name'];
```